# RotateTransform slowing the FillRectangle function in C# GDI+?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, rotatetransform

I have a function that draw points on the screen. This function worked very well until I added the line with `panelGraphics.RotateTransform`. When this line is there, the process of doing one repaint is very long. My list of points contains about 5000 points and without the rotation, it's done in a couple of milliseconds but with that line it could take up to 500 ms which is VERY slow. Do you have any idea why RotateTransform is so slow and also, what can I do to optimize this?

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    Graphics panelGraphics = panel1.CreateGraphics();

    panelGraphics.TranslateTransform((panel1.Width / 2) + _panW, (panel1.Height / 2) + _panH);

    //Problematic line...
    panelGraphics.RotateTransform(230 - Convert.ToInt32(_dPan), System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Prepend);

    PointF ptPrevious = new PointF(float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue);
    foreach (PointF pt in _listPoint)
    {
        panelGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, (pt.X / 25) * _fZoomFactor, (pt.Y / 25) * _fZoomFactor, 2, 2);
    }

    myBrush.Dispose();
    myPen.Dispose();
    panelGraphics.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that each rectangle has to be rotated. Rotation can be a slow operation, especially for none square angles.

The better approach in this case is to first create a "hidden" bitmap which you draw the rectangles into. *Then* apply the rotation to your main graphics object and draw the hidden bitmap onto your main bitmap (control). Something like this -

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

    Graphics panelGraphics = e.Graphics; //use the provided Graphics object

    // create an internal bitmap to draw rectangles to
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.ClientSize.Width, _
                            this.ClientSize.Height, _
                            Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {

        PointF ptPrevious = new PointF(float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue);
        foreach (PointF pt in _listPoint) {
            g.FillRectangle(myBrush, (pt.X / 25) * _fZoomFactor, _
                                     (pt.Y / 25) * _fZoomFactor, 2, 2);
        }   
    }

    panelGraphics.TranslateTransform((panel1.ClientSize.Width / 2) + _panW, _
                                     (panel1.ClientSize.Height / 2) + _panH);

    //Problematic line...
    panelGraphics.RotateTransform(230 - Convert.ToInt32(_dPan), _
                                  System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Prepend);

    panelGraphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0); //adjust x/y as needed
    bmp.Dispose;

    myBrush.Dispose();
    myPen.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: It only show a part of my point cloud... I thinks it's because some of my points have negative value which worked in the old Graphics context (from a panel) but doesn't seems to work with the Graphics from a bmp... Any idea how to deal with points with value like (200, -100)?

Comment: They will simply be clipped (not drawn). If you need to draw often with the points at the same relative positions it's probably better to cache the bitmap globally and just translate/rotate and then redraw the bitmap instead of render the points each time. If you move the points collectively (change their values with an offset), don't - rather introduce an external delta value that you use with the bitmap for the translation. This way negative offsets will automatically be taken care of. But this depends on the purpose - the OP doesn't say.

Comment: I did some extra treatment to assure me that I have no negative value and everything work great. Thanks!